# Exporting a session variable in a CSV file. PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to export some data from my session array as a CSV but when I include the session_start() at the head of the file instead of creating a downloadable document it echoes it to the browser. Do I need to take a different approach or is there a way to fix this from happening? Without the session_start() it creates and downloads the file but its empty because my session array is missing.

```
    header( "Content-Type: text/csv;charset=utf-8" );
    header( "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename\"" );
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    session_start(); 
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Includes/object_one.php";
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Includes/object_two.php";

    $fp= fopen('php://output', 'w');

    foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $fields){
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    exit();
```

if it helps my array is in this format:

```
$data = array(dataset1(array, of, data), dataset2(array, of, data), dataset#(array, of, data));
```

EDIT: Session_Start doesn't seem to be causing the issue but the includes do.

Comment: Use your browsers development console to find out the differences in the headers sent between the two attempts. That is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a header problem. If you print something before the header function (like a space from a file inclusion dued to a wrong php-tag closing), all headers doesn't works. Try to put `ob_clean()` before declaring headers and check if works.